# How to pass CLIs in a remote linux server from windows batch script?

Tags: windows-7, linux, ssh, batch, putty

I am able to connect to a remote linux server by using

```
    start C:\Users\pankmish\Downloads\putty.exe -ssh stag -l username -pw password
```

But Now i am trying to give linux CLIs from same batch script, Can anybody please suggest me; How to pass CLIs in remote linux sever from the batch script?

It will be very helpful if i'll any demo script for the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `-m` option if I am reading the [documentation](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-session) correctly. It specifies a file with a command to run. Multiple commands on new lines are possible, but apparently not guaranteed. Alternately, you could install a different SSH client (like [OpenSSH for Windows](http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/)) which provides the standard openssh ssh client. You then just run `ssh user@host command`. You would need to set up proper key authentication to avoid entering a password though.

Comment: I tried using -m with the command to run but the problem is it opens a  putty window and suddenly closes it, i am not able to see what's happening in the screen.